# Variable A assigned to variable B. When A changes, shouldn't A change too?

Tags: python

```
>>> a = 2
>>> b = a
>>> b
2
>>> a = 20
>>> b
2
```

Shoudn't the last instance of b also return 20, since b is assigned to a, which changed?

Comment: This is true for mutable objects, but not immutable ones like `int`.

Comment: @Coldspeed, in this case, the variable "points" at a different value, it doesn't necessarily limited to immutable objects: `a = object();
b = a;
a = object();
(a != b) == True`

Comment: Required reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, everything is an object and when you assign something, you actually just assign a reference to the object.

So think about a variable being just a label for some object that exists somewhere—Python actually calls variables “names” for that reason.

When you do `a = 2`, you give the `int` object holding the value 2 a name `a`. When you now do `b = a`, you give the object that `a` references another name `b`. So both variables will refer to the *same* object. So far so good.

When you now do `a = 20`, you change what the name `a` is referring to. You are using the name to refer to a different `int` object which holds the value 20. This does not affect the other object that is holding the value 2; that still has the name `b`. So assigning something will just relabel the objects. You are never actually modifying any object that way.

This is different to when you *mutate* an object though. The most common example is a list:

```
a = ['hello']
b = a
```

Just like before, `a` and `b` are names for the *same* `list` object. If you now mutate `b` by calling `b.append('world')`, you are mutating the object that `b` references. But `a` still refers to *the same* `list` object, so when looking at `a`, you will see those changes too:

```
>>> a = ['hello']
>>> b = a
>>> b.append('world')
>>> a
['hello', 'world']
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example, `b` is initialized as the quantity that is stored in `a`, which is 2. Then, `a` is reassigned the value of 20. However, that does not change b as `int` objects are immutable. In other words, `b` has the value that `a` was, but once `a` is changed, it does not effect is stored in `b`

```
a = 2

b = a #here, storing the contents of a in b

#b now stores 2

a = 20 #here, only changes the value that is stored in a.

#b is still 2
```

Edit:

Here is an example where b is assigned to a:

```
a = 2

b = 3

a = b #now, a stores the value that b contains

#a is now 3

#b is still 3
```

Comment: Okay. Could you also give an example where b is assigned to a, instead of its contents?

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen Please see my recent edit. Please let me know if that makes sense.